# Series with sum 1/a

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been given a homework question as follows:

> Let $a$ be a positive real number, find a method to approximate $1/a$
>   without ever having to divide, with a sequence $x_k$ such that $x_k \to 1/a$. Explain why
>   your solution works and and as much information as you can about the error.
>   Hint. Think of a geometric series whose sum is $1/a$.

I've been going through all the series I can think of and my first question is, is there a way to create a geometric series whose sum is of your choice?

(I'm also finding it confusing how a sequence could converge to some number whilst the series also sums to that same number)

Comment: What does x sub k mean ?

Comment: and what does dividing by x sub k mean ?

Comment: @Jun OK. and waht does dividing by x_k mean ?

Comment: It means finding some method of approximation which does not include the use of division.

Comment: Concerning your parenthetical comment: The sequence $(x_k)$ is the sequence of partial sums of the series.

Answer (score 4):

Sum the series

$$S_k = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} (1-a)^n = \frac{1-(1-a)^k}{1-(1-a)} = \frac{1}{a} [1-(1-a)^k]$$

Then

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} S_k =  \frac{1}{a}$$

This only works, of course, when $|1-a| < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Apply [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to the equation
$$
f(x)=\frac1x-a=0.
$$
Choose a first approximation $x_0$ and define
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n(2-a\,x_n),\quad n\ge1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{1-(1-a)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-a)^i$$
$$|1-a|<1\Rightarrow -1<1-a<1\Rightarrow 0<a<2,$$

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers basically cover it, but I thought I would post an answer that works for all $a$.  Choose $\varepsilon$ such that $0<\varepsilon a < 1$, and let $y_{k}=\varepsilon(1-\varepsilon a)^{k}$.  Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}y_k= \varepsilon\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\varepsilon a\right)^k=\frac{\varepsilon}{1-(1-\varepsilon a)}=\frac{1}{a}
$$
and is convergent, so the partial sums $x_k\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{k}y_i \rightarrow 1/a$.